# Angularjs save variables $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

There's a way to save variables inside the `$routeProvider`?

Ex: I was trying to set the aside menu when a reach a certain page. 
The idea is do like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    title: 'Home',
    controller: 'Home',
    variable: 'active'
});
```

And in the HTML:

```
<a href="/Home" class="{{$route.variable}}">
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27537048/885626

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: Passing params from $routeProvider to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533386/angular-passing-params-from-routeprovider-to-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Route provider**

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    title: 'test.html',
    controller: 'Home',
    resolve: {
         setParams: function ($route) { $route.current.params.variable = 'active'; }
    }
})
```

**Controller**

Use `$routeParams` dependency

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
     $scope.variable = $routeParams.variable;      
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="/Home" ng-class="variable">
```

Comment: The `$$` properties in Angular are suggested to be private and should not be called directly

Comment: Indeed - good for noticing - updated answer using `$routeParams` on the resolve function to manual set the current `$route` params object.

Comment: `$routeParams` is not injected into your controller correctly

Answer (score 0):

You said you are already setting a static property in the route object.

All you need to do is in your HomeController make a variable which can be access in html, i.e.

```
$scope.route = $route;
//or
vm.route = $route;
```

So the HomeController will now look like :

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $route) {
 $scope.route = $route;      
}
```

and the HTML would just have a small change, i.e.

```
<a href="/Home" class="{{route.current.variable}}">
```

and its done!