# Unable to fetch data from controller into view using ng-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ngroute

**Controller part**

Below is the controller part, here I am unable to fetch data from controller aa and bb into html pages Students and courses respectively

```
/// <reference path="Angularmin.js" />
/// <reference path="angular_route.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Users\prerna.bhadwal\Documents\projects\practice_angular\practice_angular\HtmlPage2.html"


var app = angular.module('mod', ['ngRoute']);

//var app = angular.module('mod', []);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider

 .when("/Students", {
     templateUrl: "Templates/Courses.html",
     controller:"aa"
 })
 .when("/Courses", {
     templateUrl: "Templates/Students.html",
     controller: "bb"
 })
})
 .controller("aa", function ($scope) {

 $scope.msg = "hello how r";
}).controller("bb", function ($scope) {

 $scope.msg1 = "hhhhhh";

})
```

**Html page part**

This is the html part from where I am routing to students and courses html pages:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html ng-app="mod">
 <head>
     <!--<script src="Scripts/Controller2.js"></script>-->
 
     <script src="Scripts/Angularmin.js"></script>
     <script src="Scripts/Controller.js"></script>
     <script src="Scripts/angular_route.js"></script>
 
     <title></title>
 </head>
 <body >
     <!--<a href="#/Students">students</a>
         <a href="#/Courses">courses</a>-->
     <!--<div>
        {{datafromservice}} datafromservice
     </div>-->-->
 
 
     <a href="#/Students">Red</a>
     <a href="#Courses">Green</a>
 
 
     <div ng-view></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is the html page for students:

```
 <div>
     <ul>
         <li>Student class A</li>
         <li>Student Class B</li>
         <li>{{msg}}</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

This is the html page for courses:

```
 <div>
     <ul>
         <li>Maths</li>
         <li>Science</li>
         <li>{{msg1}}</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: ` <a href="#Courses">Green</a>` isn't that a typo?

Comment: check this to know how to pass values while routing... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533386/angular-passing-params-from-routeprovider-to-controller

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying... 
Passing values into the routes...

complete code in the snippet... and in the students.htm, kindly insert line the  will be the following...

**INSERT THIS IN YOUR... students.htm**

```
 <li>{{gottenValue}}</li>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('mod', ['ngRoute']);

//var app = angular.module('mod', []);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when("/Students", {
     templateUrl: "students.htm",
     controller:"aa",
     passValue: 'exampleA'
 })
 .when("/Courses", {
     templateUrl: "rootScope.htm",
     controller: "myCtrl"
 })
})
 .controller("aa", function ($scope, $route) {
    $scope.msg = "hello how r u ";
    $scope.gottenValue = $route.current.$$route.passValue;
    console.log($scope.gottenValue);

    $scope.passValue
}).controller("bb", function ($scope) {
 $scope.msg1 = "hhhhhh";
});
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    
    <div ng-app="mod">
       <!--<a href="#/Students">students</a>
         <a href="#/Courses">courses</a>-->
     <!--<div>
        {{datafromservice}} datafromservice
     </div>-->-->


     <a href="#!Students">Red</a>
     <a href="#!Courses">Green</a>


     <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
```